# OnValidate VB.Net partial method wont fire for NerdDinner sample code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am having a problem that [gfrizzle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23935/gfrizzle) said he had had but then said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666678/implementing-partial-void-in-vb) that he fixed it.  I looked at the post and implemented what it said to do, but it still doesn’t work for me (if gfrizzle sees this, I would like to see his code)

To restate the problem, I want to create business rules that are seperated from the DAL code that is generated by my L2S model.  Per the NerdDinner example (which is written in C#) this code needs to be in a partial class like mine is below.

If anybody can help let me know my partial class in my controller class code is written below

```
<HandleError()> _
Public Class PreOrderController
  Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  Private db As New FOTAZDataContext  'with EF this would be FOTAZDBEntities, see the web.config

  ' GET: /PreOrder/Create
  Function Create() As ActionResult
    Dim registrationToCreate As New Registration()
    PopulateDropDownListBoxesForCreate()
    Return View()
  End Function

  ' POST: /PreOrder/Create  include:="MerchandiseID,Quantity"
  <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
  Function Create(<Bind(Exclude:="ID")> ByVal preOrderToCreate As PreOrder) As ActionResult

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
      Try
        preOrderToCreate.RegistrationID = GetRegistrationID()
        db.PreOrders.InsertOnSubmit(preOrderToCreate)
        db.SubmitChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
      Catch
        For Each issue In preOrderToCreate.GetRuleViolations()
          ModelState.AddModelError(issue.PropertyName, issue.ErrorMessage)
        Next
      End Try
    End If
    PopulateDropDownListBoxesForCreate()
    Return View("Create")

  End Function

  Sub PopulateDropDownListBoxesForCreate()
    Dim merchandise = db.Merchandises.ToList()
    ViewData("MerchandiseID") = New SelectList(merchandise, "ID", "Descr")
  End Sub


Imports System.Data.Linq
Partial Public Class PreOrder

  Public ReadOnly Property IsValid() As Boolean
    Get
      Return (GetRuleViolations().Count() = 0)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function GetRuleViolations() As IEnumerable(Of RuleViolation)
    Dim ret = New List(Of RuleViolation)()

    If Not IsNumeric(Quantity) Then
      ret.Add(New RuleViolation("Quantity", "Quantity is not numeric"))
    End If
    Return ret

  End Function

  'This isn't getting called.
  Private Sub OnValidate(ByVal action As ChangeAction)
    If Not IsValid Then
      Throw New ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you edit your question remove all the html from the code sample, then highlight your code sample in the editor click the icon which looks like binary code. This will do syntax highlighting thanks

Comment: Could you please use the "code formating" option so we can actually see your code ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out (more or less).  I got the order of the two parameters backwards...

```
ret.Add(New RuleViolation("Quantity", "Quantity is not numeric"))
```

should be

```
ret.Add(New RuleViolation("Quantity is not numeric", "Quantity"))
```

I still don't fill that I fully understand this.  Oh well.